# Can Netbeans use regex to make my own 'format code' functions?

Tags: regex, arrays, netbeans, formatting

I was searching for a function, or a 'format code' function in NetBeans to format my arrays in PHP in a proper way.

E.g.:

```
$arr1 = array('allow',' => array('index', 'admin', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'delete'),' => array('@'),), array('deny', 'users' => array('*'),);
```

^^ Is quite hard to read. So if there would be a function to search for:

- everytime there is a `array(` followed by `'` replace it with an `array(\n'`.

or

- everytime there is `,\s'\w+'` followed by `=>` replace `,\s'` with `,\s\n'`

Does anyone know if there is a plugin for that? (Btw, I'm not a star in regex so I'm just looking for the array() format problem.)

Comment: NetBeans does natively allow you to format code as you type or format a file (Source -> Format). Specify settings for this formatting in Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting (7.0.1). I don't know if it applies to PHP as well or if it's adequate for your needs.

Comment: Yes I know that, but there is no way of customization possible in the `Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting` window for arrays